# Acquire Video File Metadata From S3

Tags: javascript, video, amazon-s3, video-streaming, html5-video

Setup: I'm working on a video upload tool. I use a 3rd party javascript library that loads content from a users various storage locations (Hard Drive, Dropbox, Facebook, etc )

The library pushes the videos to our S3 bucket and returns the url of the uploaded file.

Goal: I would like to get the metadata (Height / Width / Duration / Etc) about the video without having to load the entire video binary.

Context: I use a service that handles video transcoding, and eventually posts the transcoded metadata to one of our backend servers. The transcoding can take a few minutes.

I need to get the temporary metadata of the uploaded file, but i don't want to load the full video.

Answer (score 0):

Setting preload="metadata" on an HTML video tag means the browser is supposed to fetch metadata but not the whole stream. It's only considered a hint, i.e., browsers are not required to follow it, but you could try it and see if it works on the browsers you need to support. What it should do, I believe, is fetch just the first part of the video file, so it can read the header.

If that doesn't work, you probably need to implement a separate Ajax call to fetch the metadata. Hopefully your transcoding service gives you the metadata in a way that you can access it server-side. Otherwise you might need to extract it yourself, on the server. For example, you could use the ffmpeg library (or spawn an ffmpeg command line process) to parse out the metadata.